# spring property-placeholder always give default value

Tags: spring

In below example, I found that sampleWeight is always taken as default 0.0 irrespective of any value in placeHolder. If I remove the default value then it picks up the correct placeHolder value.

```
@Configuration
public class XYZConfiguration {

@Value("${properties.xyz:0.0}")
private double sampleWeightWithDefault;

@Value("${{properties.xyz}")
private double sampleWeight;

@Bean(initMethod = "start", destroyMethod = "stop")
Profile profiler() {
  LOGGER.error("sampleWeightWithDefault:" + sampleWeightWithDefault);
  LOGGER.error("sampleWeight:" + sampleWeight);
  return new Profile(sampleWeight);
}
```

o/p: 
sampleWeightWithDefault:0.0
sampleWeight:1.0

Comment: Is the `{{` just a typo?

Comment: Just a typo during copying